# Divs created with javascript not aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little list of events and a button to add events.

The idea is that the button appends new events to the page. My problem is that the new events added to the page do not have a margin to the right, so the events are not aligned with the others.

```js
function addEvent() {
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
  iDiv.innerHTML = "Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br>\
  Data: 1/7/2017<br>\
  Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br>\
  Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br>\
  Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br>\
  Foto: Alguma foto";
  iDiv.className = "event";
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.event {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px black double;
  padding: 2%;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAFA1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addEvent()">Add New Event</button><br>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hot el do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    Nome: Front In Sampa 6a edição<br> Data: 1/7/2017<br> Horário: 8:00 - 19:00<br> Local: Teatro hotel do Maksoud Plaza: R. São Carlos do Pinhal, 424 - Bela Vista, São Paulo<br> Organizadores: Front In Sampa<br> Foto: Alguma foto
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fact that the divs not added by JavaScript line up are a fluke due to the white space in your code.

Comment: margin auto 0; can cause alignment problems.. work with margin/padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is causing due to display: inline-block.

Here, is what you can do,

1) Remove **Display: inline-block**

2) Add **Float: left** instead

3) Add **margin-left: 3px;** (if you want to have the same effect)

```
.event {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  border: 2px black double;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

Note: Dont forget to add the following line after all the div's have been appended, to clear the floating of the divs.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Not a fan of clearing DIVs. It's 2017 and there's more appropriate solutions than adding extraneous markup.

Comment: True, Well but that's just a part of the solutionI gave. I dint want to create a new issue while fixing the existing one.

Comment: FWIW, using a clearfix wouldn't have created a new issue. It's fine that it's a part of your solution, just dated is all.

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin:auto; and add something like margin-right: 3px; that will work.

Comment: in .event in the css